# Calculated Control in Access

Tags: ms-access, calculated-field

I have a simple table

```
Contract#    Customer#
aaa111       123
bbb222       453
ccc333       232
ddd444       23X
```

When I bring it up as a report I want to have some calculated firleds in the header that will count the number of Customers and the number of contracts.  But when I create a report and `type =Count([Customer#])`
and `=Count(Contract#])` into the Control Source of a text box I get an error in the Report View.  This same syntax works on a Form but not a report.  Why won't it work in a report?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you inserting the textbox in the report header or page header? The first one works fine the second generates an error. If you want to insert the text box in a page header, you can use the `DCount` function instead.

Comment: Ok.  Thanks.  It works in the report header.  But it won't take a conditional, for instance =count([Customer#]= '123').  It just counts all the customers and returns 4.  In the future I will have more than one record for each customer number.

Comment: for those purposes, use the `DCount`, as follows : `=DCount([Customer#],[TableName],[Customer#]='123')`